# Comparar valores de um vetor com uma matriz

Tags: java, portugol

Sou novo aqui e iniciante na programação, gostaria da ajuda de vocês, preciso fazer um algoritmo que simule a mega sena, devo apresentar uma matriz com apostadores e dezenas apostadas, um vetor com os números do sorteio, tudo isso com sorteio automático e sem repetição, e no final do algoritmo mostrar quantas pessoas acertaram 0, 1,2,3,4,5 e 6 dezenas.

O meu problema está em comparar os valores do vetor sorteio com a matriz de apostadores e achar quantas pessoas acertaram 0 números e assim por diante..

Segue o que eu já consegui fazer.

```
programa
{
     inclua biblioteca Util


     funcao inicio()
     {
          const inteiro apostadores = 100
          const inteiro nDezenasApostada = 6
          const inteiro dezenas = 6
          inteiro megaApostas[apostadores][nDezenasApostada]
          inteiro nSorteados[dezenas]
          inteiro zeroAcertos = 0
          inteiro umAcerto = 0
          inteiro doisAcertos = 0
          inteiro tresAcertos = 0
          inteiro quatroAcertos = 0
          inteiro cincoAcertos = 0
          inteiro seisAcertos = 0

// Preenche a matriz com numeros sorteados aleatórios e não repetidos 

          para (inteiro i = 0; i < apostadores; i++) {
               para (inteiro j = 0; j < nDezenasApostada; j++) {
                    inteiro numeros = Util.sorteia(1, 60)
                    inteiro contador = 0
                    enquanto (contador < nDezenasApostada) {
                         se (megaApostas[i][contador] == numeros) {
                              numeros = Util.sorteia(1, 60)
                              contador = 0
                         }
                         contador++
                    }
                    megaApostas[i][j] = numeros
               }
          }
          escreva("Numeros Sorteados: ")

// Preenche o vetor de sorteio com numeros sorteados aleatórios e não repetidos

          para (inteiro i = 0; i < dezenas; i++) {
               inteiro numeros = Util.sorteia(1, 60)
               inteiro contador = 0
               enquanto (contador < dezenas) {
                    se (nSorteados[contador] == numeros) {
                         numeros = Util.sorteia(1, 60)
                         contador = 0
                    }
                    contador++
               }
               nSorteados[i] = numeros
               escreva(" ", nSorteados[i])
          }
          escreva("\n")

     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa tarde, segue exemplo de código em c para solucionar o problema.

Obs.: O código pode ser otimizado, fiz rapidinhos somente para demonstrar.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#define TOTAL_APOSTADORES 100
#define N_DEZENAS 6
#define MAX 60

int main()
{

    srand(time(NULL));

    int dezenasSorteadas [N_DEZENAS];

    printf("Dezenas sorteadas: \n");

    for (int i = 0; i < N_DEZENAS; i++) {
        dezenasSorteadas[i] = rand() % MAX + 1;

        printf("%d ", dezenasSorteadas[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    int apostadores [TOTAL_APOSTADORES][N_DEZENAS];

    for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL_APOSTADORES; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N_DEZENAS; j++) {
            apostadores[i][j] = rand() % MAX + 1;
        }       
    }


    int totalPorTotal[N_DEZENAS+1] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };



    for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL_APOSTADORES; i++) {
        int totalAcertos = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < N_DEZENAS; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < N_DEZENAS; k++) {
                if (dezenasSorteadas[k] == apostadores[i][j]) {
                    totalAcertos++;
                }
            }

        }

        switch(totalAcertos) {
            case 0: totalPorTotal[0]++; break;
            case 1: totalPorTotal[1]++; break;
            case 2: totalPorTotal[2]++; break;
            case 3: totalPorTotal[3]++; break;
            case 4: totalPorTotal[4]++; break;
            case 5: totalPorTotal[5]++; break;
            case 6: totalPorTotal[6]++; break;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N_DEZENAS+1; i++) {
        printf("Total com %d acertos: %d\n", i, totalPorTotal[i]);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Saída:

```
Dezenas sorteadas: 
9 13 28 30 45 10 
Total com 0 acertos: 48
Total com 1 acertos: 39
Total com 2 acertos: 11
Total com 3 acertos: 1
Total com 4 acertos: 1
Total com 5 acertos: 0
Total com 6 acertos: 0
```

Comment: Perfeito, eu estava usando apenas 2 for e não tava resetando o valor da variavel de acertos, tava passando direto! falta apenas arrumar a repetição dos numeros sorteados!

Comment: Show de bola! Abraço.